# Problem controlling 3 servos of different types

Tags: pi-3b+, pwm, driver

I had a remote developer do code for 3 servos to control a mechanism. He  made sure to aquire similar hardware. Rpi4 and 16channel pwm driver. He used 3 sg90 servos. I have 1 sg90 and 2 smaller servos. His set up worked but no servos even moved at my place. He figured my servos did not work o 3.3 signal but on 5v. I asked him to send me his working set up. He did and it worked and I theb even tried my servos on his rpi and driver and this worked too initially. But when using the servos on the application, for some reason only one channel at a time works. Always the channel 0 works but other servos on other channels not. So the developer still though it had to do with the 3.3v signal incomptibility so he had sent me a logic 3.3v to 5v converter. So i connected the driver to the rpi via the logic converter But same problem. Only one servo works at a time. Always on channel 0. If i switch servos it still is the channel 0. Then we tried using 1,2,3 channels instead and then its the channel 1 that works. So why did it work at first then later this bug?

Comment: Try writing in paragraphs

Comment: Look at some of the thousands of answered questions on this site.  See the sort of information supplied.  Supply that information.

Comment: the problem is on line 25 of the code

Comment: 95% of your post is clutter ... we do not need a story about the past ... we need to know about now ... what you have, how it is connected, what is your code, what are the expected results, what are the observed results, what is your question